# SOAP::Lite pass an argument as the class

Tags: perl, soaplite

I have next schema:

```
   <xs:schema        xmlns:tns="http://common.balance.contract.kernel.bgbilling.bitel.ru/"     xmlns:ns1="http://common.bitel.ru"   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    version="1.0"targetNamespace="http://common.balance.contract.kernel.bgbilling .bitel.ru/">
    <xs:import namespace="http://common.bitel.ru" s    chemaLocation="http://xxx:8080/bgbilling/executer/ru.bitel.bgbilling.kernel.contract.balance/PaymentService?xsd=1"/>
    <xs:element name="BGException" type="tns:BGException"/>
…
    <xs:element name="paymentUpdate" type="tns:paymentUpdate"/>
    <xs:element name="paymentUpdateResponse" type="tns:paymentUpdateResponse"/>
    <xs:complexType name="BGException">
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="message" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="tag" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="payment">
    <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="tns:abstractBalanceBean">
    <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="abstractBalanceBean" abstract="true">
    <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="ns1:id">
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="comment" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="contractId" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="date" type="xs:dateTime"/>
    <xs:attribute name="sum" type="xs:decimal"/>
    <xs:attribute name="summa" type="xs:decimal"/>
    <xs:attribute name="timeChange" type="xs:dateTime"/>
    <xs:attribute name="typeId" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="userId" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
    </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="paymentUpdate">
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="payment" type="tns:payment" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="distribution" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

Please, tell me how i must send arguments in method paymentUpdate (in Perl) ?

```
$client->call('paymentUpdate'=>SOAP::Data->type("namesp1:paymentUpdate")->...
```

What to write on?
How to create and send the desired type (paymentUpdate) ?

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute, here is the solution:

```
$wsdl = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:8080/bgbilling/executer/ru.bitel.bgbilling.kernel.contract.balance/PaymentService?wsdl";
       @comment = ("<comment>$comment</comment>");
       $authoriz = 'Basic '.encode_base64('login:password');
       #$SOAP::Constants::PREFIX_ENV = 'SOAP-ENV';
       #$SOAP::Constants::PREFIX_ENC = "SOAP-ENC";
       $client = SOAP::Lite->new(service=>$wsdl);
       $client->proxy($wsdl);
       $client->ns("http://common.balance.contract.kernel.bgbilling.bitel.ru/","ns1");
       $client->outputxml('true');
       $client->transport->http_request->headers->push_header('Authorization' => $authoriz );
       $soap = $client->service($wsdl.'?wsdl');
       my $pm = SOAP::Data->new(name=>"payment");
       $pm->type("ts:payment");
       $pm->attr({ id => "$id", contractId=>"$cid", date=>"$dt", sum=>"$sum",    summa=>"$sum", typeId=>"3", userId=>"0"});
       $pm->value(@comment);
       print $client->call('paymentUpdate',$pm);
```